# Use python to add to javascript array in javascript file

Tags: javascript, python, arrays

I have this array stored in `versions.js`

```
var cc_versions = [

    "2016-01-22",
    "2016-01-21",

];

var cs_versions = [

    "2016-01-23",
    "2016-01-21",

];
```

I have been trying to figure out a way to write new data to the top of the array inside the javascript file with python. I run a python script on my computer almost every day and I want to update this array when I run it so that I can have a website load the versions. Is it possible to do this? I know I could write to the file, but it would just go to the bottom of the file outside of the array. Also there will be multiple arrays, so I'm trying to find some python script that can interact with a javascript file so I can target specific arrays.

Comment: How about you read from file, modify the list and then write to file?

Comment: would that work with multiple arrays, how would I modify the list?

Comment: I would parse it as JSON into a Python Object, modify it, and put it back into a JSON Object.

Comment: does the array need to be in the `.js` file itself? If you could modify `versions.js` to read from a JSON file, that would be a lot easier to work with.

Comment: I just need something that I can process with jquery, so json would be completely fine

Answer (score 0):

You could also try using Genshi template language. One of the tags there is

```
<?python ... ?>
```

for example:

```
<?python
        import json
        dateInit = []
        selectInit = []
        for fi in form_items:
            if (fi["type"] == "date"):
                dateInit.append(fi["id"])
            if "attrs" in fi and "format-select" in fi["attrs"]:
                selectInit.append(fi["id"])
            if not "attrs" in fi:
                fi["attrs"] = {}
        jsonDateInit = json.dumps(dateInit)
        jsonSelectInit = json.dumps(selectInit)
  ?>
```

Your response should contain form_items dictionary processed somewhere on the back-end. Then in javascript you can 'accept' the variables using '$'-sign:

```
var dateitems = JSON.stringify($jsonDateInit);
var select_items = JSON.stringify($jsonSelectInit);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import json


NEW_VARIABLES = [1, 2, 3]

with open('your/json/file.json') as data_file:
    json_data = json.load(data_file)

# insert at the beginning of the list
json_data['cc_version'].insert(0, 'something new')
json_data['cs_version'] = NEW_VARIABLES + json_data['cs_version']


# write to json file after modifying data

with open('your/json/file.json', 'w') as output_file:
    json.dump(json_data, output_file)
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using json as suggested in the comments

```
import json
with open("cc_versions.txt") as data:
    json = json.load(data)

dates = json["dates"]

dates.append("2016-01-21")
dates = set(dates)
dates = sorted(dates, key=lambda d: map(int, d.split('-')))
dates = dates[::-1]

import json    
with open("cc_versions.txt", "w") as outfile:
    json.dump({'dates':dates}, outfile, indent=4)
```